# selective routing through a VPN tunnel

Tags: linux, vpn, routing, ipsec, tunnel

The problem: after establishing an **IPsec VPN tunnel** all traffic is routed to the remote endpoint, while I *only* need to route the packets destined to that internal network and still be able to access the **internet** on my local machine. Currently, when I enable the according VPN connection - all connectivity drops, meaning it's not possible to reach this machine over my LAN or access the internet through it (there is a restriction on the remote end for further WAN forwarding). So, only the VPN works in this case.

The topology: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cTDr.png

I'm using **OpenSwan** on a **Debian**-based distro and also behind **NAT** (traversal enabled).

Here are the details of **ipsec.conf**:

> version   2.0
>
> config setup
>     plutodebug="none"
>     plutoopts="--perpeerlog"
>     plutoopts="--interface=wlan2"
>     dumpdir=/var/run/pluto/
>     nat_traversal=yes
>     virtual_private=%v4:10.196.0.0/17,%v4:!192.168.1.0/24
>     oe=off
>     protostack=netkey
>
> conn z
>       authby=secret
>       keylife=1h
>       pfs=yes
>       auto=add
>       phase2alg=aes128-sha1;modp1024
>       keyingtries=3
>       ikelifetime=8h
>       type=tunnel
>       left=192.168.1.76
>       leftsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
>       leftprotoport=0/0
>       right=y.y.y.y
>       rightsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
>       rightprotoport=0/0

Here are partial details of **ifconfig**:

> wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:13:02:46:42:8d
>             UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>             RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
>             RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
>
> wlan2     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 94:0c:6d:8d:28:0f
>             inet addr:192.168.1.76  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
>             inet6 addr: fe80::960c:6dff:fe8d:280f/64 Scope:Link
>             UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>             RX packets:125221 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:89332 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
>             RX bytes:151498702 (151.4 MB)  TX bytes:18233148 (18.2 MB)

Here are the details of **route -n**:

> Kernel IP routing table
>   Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
>   0.0.0.0         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan2
>   169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlan2
>   192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     2      0        0 wlan2

As you can see - the machine is connected over **WiFi** on **wlan2** and this is the interface that is taking part in the VPN setup. So, what would you suggest doing, in order to solve the problem of losing internet access after enabling the tunnel? Thank you.

Comment: Urm, AFIK, this is the correct behaviour for a VPN. When setting up a VPN connection, you are making a hole into a remote *local* network and you need to have all traffic routed through that network for security. If you allow some traffic to bypass the VPN, it is a significant security risk.

Answer (score 4):

This is the problem:

> rightsubnet=0.0.0.0/0

with this line you tell openswan that the endpoint of the tunnel is "everything", so all packets are routed through the vpn.

Replace 0.0.0.0/0 with the network(s) you want to reach behind the gateway. The config on the client and server has to match, so edit both.